How to connect my Java app to an Azure CosmosDB service with no public access?
This was asked on stackoverflow and is a copy.
My Java app is using gradle and the mongo-spring starter dependency: implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb').
I can connect to a publicly accessible CosmosDB with just inputting these environment variables and the mongo starter takes care of the rest. I do not have a config file for Cosmos.
MONGO_DB_HOST= cosmos-public.mongo.cosmos.azure.com
MONGO_DB_DATABASE_NAME= test-db
MONGO_DB_USERNAME= cosmos-public
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD= [primary password]
MONGO_DB_PORT= 10255
MONGO_DB_URI= mongo://cosmos-public:[password]@cosmos-public:10255/?ssl=true

I also have a CosmosDB Mongo service that has its public access disabled.

Under "Private access" it has the connection to a private endpoint cosmos-private-private-endpoint
The private endpoint is connected to a virtual network/subnet called nonprod-vnet/private-endpoints
The private endpoint has a DNS configuration. There are 2 FDQNs:

cosmos-private.privatelink.mongo.cosmos.azure.com
cosmos-private-eastus2.privatelink.mongo.csomos.azure.com


I am not able to access data about the Private DNS zone, as that is owned by someone else.

Can I just change my environment variables in my Java app to change it to access this private CosmosDB service? Or is there more involved I don't know about?
